# Help need in Mathematica or Sage

Tags: polynomials, math-software, mathematica, sagemath

I want to find the common positive solutions of two polynomials $f_{a,b}(x,y)$, $g_{a,b}(x,y)$ where $a,b$ runs from 0  to 1 with an interval 0.01. Let $(x_0,y_0)$ be a common positive solution. Then I want
evaluate a third polynomial $h_{a,b}(x_0,y_0)$. If this value is less than zero, I will change $b$ accordingly.

I have this tried in Mathamatica but could not succeed as follows:
b=0
For[$a=0,a<1,a=a+0.01$, Solve[{$x^2$-$ax$+$by$==0, $2xa+y^2-5ab==0$},{$x,y$}]].

Answer (score 2):

First, remember that `Solve[]` returns its solutions as "rules" of the form `{{x -> (*something*), y -> (*something*)}, ...}`; what you can then do is `{x, y} /. Solve[(*stuff*)]` and then use the `Select[]` function accordingly (by construcing an appropriate test function, perhaps using `>` or `Positive[]`), after which you can then substitute into your third expression.

Comment: To add to Dennis's solution (since I can't comment there), you have the choice of joining together equations and inequalities with `||` and `&&`, or collecting them in a list, like `Reduce[{x^2 - a x + b y == 0, 2 x a + y^2 - 5 a b == 0, x > 0, y > 0}, {x, y}]`. You can then use `ToRules[]` for postprocessing the output of `Reduce[]`. Note that it is a good idea to use `1/100` instead of `0.01` as the increment here so that you are working with exact values all throughout.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

`Table[Reduce[
  x^2 - a x + b y == 0 && 2 x a + y^2 - 5 a b == 0, {x, y}], {a, 
  0, 1, 0.01}, {b, 0, 1, 0.01}]`

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help.